# export a dictionary to csv file : d={key : value} value is a list

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary, export-to-csv

I'm trying to output my dictionary as a CSV file. But I didn't manage to do it properly. my output file looks very bad. Does anyone have an idea of how to put values coming from in the same key in the same column?

```
dico = {'names': ['Jimmy', 'Drew'], 'age':[25, 30]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([dico])
df.to_csv('file.csv', sep='\t',header=True, index=False, mode='w')


# output file looks like this:
age names
[25, 30]    ['Jimmy', 'Drew']
```

I also tried:

```
with open('mycsvfile.csv','w' ) as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=dico.keys())
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerow(dico)
```

But the problem is the same

Comment: How do you expect the output file to look like?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in dataframe creation. If you take a look at df, each cell contains an array:

```
>>> df
        age          names
0  [25, 30]  [Jimmy, Drew]
```

Replace the creation line with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dico)
```

And csv will be saved as needed.